# Tables importance (HTML)

Tags: html

I’m checking out the Intermediate HTML section in Colt Steele’s The Web Developer Bootcamp, and the first thing he has there is tables. I’ve done this part of the course before, but now I wonder, who even uses tables? (except SQL people)

If you’re a front end dev, do you still use/display tables in your projects? Even if you’re not, what is the importance of learning tables?

Answer (score 0):

It depends, sometimes we need it sometimes we don't, the reason is there is because back in the day front-end developers need to have flexibility to implement clickable images and links in every location of the site and the easiest way to achieve that is using table.

By using tables, front-end developer can slice images and links and fit into table without worrying much about design limitation, since designer can do whatever they want in an image.

These technique becomes obsolete as it is bad for SEO and maintenance sake (updating text in image is troublesome), non-dynamic since those are not real text and not responsive in mobile platform...

Later on CSS **floats** were used to position text and images rather than tables, but styling this is difficult. To overcome this the latest technique will be using CSS3 **flexbox**.

Although it seems like we don't need to use table anymore but in fact we still do, we use it when we need display data in a more readable format, *e.g. latest price list, or comparison table in an article.*

Another good thing about table is it doesn't require much styling and CSS knowledge, back-end text editor will still provide option for table so that editor can construct basic looking table from their end.